# CLion show comments for the function?

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

When I use CLion on Linux, and when I simply hover my cursor over a function, it will automatically show that function's comment written in the header file. However, on Mac, it doesn't automatically show the comment.

What's this feature called? How to explicitly set this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's "Show quick documentation on mouse move"